# Sizing the viewport to the browser's dimensions

Tags: css, resize, viewport, autoresize

I would like to present a demo of a tablet application on a website (targeting desktop browsers).
I chose an iPad 2 for the demo whose resolution is 1024x768. Adding an iPad transparent graphic cover, the demo final size is 1210x1315px.

With such a resolution, most of the screens will be too small to display the demo properly.
I don't want to resize manually all the design, or to use CSS `transform` without knowing the relevant scale. Therefore, I'm looking for a way to resize automatically the design according to the available display resolution.

I tried to use the `@-viewport`property with no success...

Here is my non working code:

```
@media (min-height: 1400px) { /* if the screen's height is smaller than 1400px... */
    @-viewport{
        height:1400px; /* ... then, let's pretend it's 1400px high*/
    }
}
```

I also tried this :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=1400, initial-scale=1" />
```

---

EDIT : jQuery workaround:

```
function resize(){
    var documentHeight = $(document).innerHeight();
    var targetedHeight = 1500;
    if (documentHeight < targetedHeight){
        var ratio = documentHeight / targetedHeight;
        $('#container').css('transform','scale('+ratio+')');
        $('#container').css('-webkit-transform','scale('+ratio+')');
        $('#container').css('-moz-transform','scale('+ratio+')');
        $('#container').css('-ms-transform','scale('+ratio+')');
        $('#container').css('-o-transform','scale('+ratio+')');
    }
}
```

This is what I finally did to achieve the expected result. I would have prefered a pure CSS solution...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using media queries: [Logic in Media Queries](http://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/)

Comment: I guess so. Therefore I edited my question by adding some code. I must be more or less misunderstanding the @-viewport concept...